Oracle SQL 11gR2 linux spool to xls -> German Umlaute not working
I’m working on an Oracle 11g database (Oracle Database 11.2.0.4.0) with linux sqlplus and I need to export query results to a file that can be opened in Excel. The data includes German umlauts (Ä, Ö, Ü), and I’m having trouble getting them to display correctly. I’ve tried both HTML (XLS-like) and CSV approaches.
What I’ve Tried:
1.) Using HTML Markup (result.xls):
I ran something like:
sql
Copy code
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SPOOL result.xls
SELECT * FROM my_table;
SPOOL OFF

This produces an HTML file, which I can open in Excel. However, umlauts don’t display correctly.
2.) I tried setting NLS_LANG before running sqlplus:
export NLS_LANG=GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8

This changed the language of the SQL*Plus prompts but did not fix the umlauts in the output file.
3.) I also attempted using:
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON ENCODING "UTF8"

inside my sql File but got an SP2-0158: unknown SET option "ENCODING" error, likely because I’m on Oracle 11g and that feature is not supported in this version of SQL*Plus.
4.) I tried NLS_LANG=GERMAN_GERMANY.WE8MSWIN1252 to match a code page that includes umlauts, but Excel still didn’t display the characters correctly.
What I Want to Achieve:
I want a straightforward method to generate a file from SQLPlus on Oracle 11g that I can just double-click in Excel and have all umlauts (Ä, Ö, Ü) display correctly without manual import steps. Is there a recommended approach for older SQLPlus versions to ensure umlauts are displayed correctly in Excel by default?
Thank you in advance!

You need to set NLS_LANG according to the character set of your terminal. Then it should work. However, you may have to edit the HTML file and declare which character set is used in the file.

Since HTML ON in your version doesn’t support ENCODING, switch to plain CSV output.
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET COLSEP ";"

SPOOL result.csv
SELECT * FROM my_table;
SPOOL OFF
EXIT;

ORRRRR try with iconv:
iconv -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1252 result.csv -o result_converted.csv
Hope it helps.
